# Firebase permission denied while reading data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read some data from a Firebase Realtime Database but I every time when I try to I'm receiving Database Error with message Permission denied. This is the code which I'm using to read the data.

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userId = currentUser.getUid();

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setFullName(ds.child("users").child(userId).getValue(User.class).getFullName());
                user.setEmail(ds.child("users").child(userId).getValue(User.class).getEmail());
                Log.i("info", " User Full name" + user.getFullName());
                userFullName.setText(user.getFullName());
                userEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("Info", "" + databaseError.getMessage());
        }

    });
```

Also these are my database rules

```
  {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also this is the data inside the database. 
[image]

What I tried to do? 
 - I did two thing first I set the database rules to public but that didn't worked for me, second thing that I did was instead of using the `addValueEventListener` I used `addChildEventListener` but that also didn't worked.

So if anyone have idea where I'm making the mistake please share it with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you're saying that the onCancelled() callback is being called?  What exactly did you do when you sid you "set the database rules to public"?

Comment: What does it mean when you sayd you "set the database rules to public"?

Comment: I suspected that It's up to the database rules as I said i set them up to

  `{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
  }
}` But this didn't helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database rules are correct, the problem is in the database reading code. You can directly set the `DatabaseReference` to `/users/<userId>`, and then directly convert the `DataSnapshot`'s value to the `User` class.

Here is the code :

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

        userFullName.setText(user.getFullName());
        userEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but neither one of the two methods triggered I still can't understand.

Comment: I did a quick log of the databaseReference and it printed an URL of the user which means it found the right user but unfortunately no data was retrieved.

Comment: I found where my mistake was thanks for the response it's working now. I voted up and accepted your answer.

Comment: How exactly you solved this issue. Please share. I am facing same problem from 2 days.